# Impossible export django-parler translated fields with the common comand dumpdata

Tags: python, django, django-parler

Is there any way to dump and load data with a `TranslatableModel` because with the common `python manage.py dumpdata app.Organization -o fixtures/organizations.json` Django command translated fields do not appear in the file.

models.py:

```
class Organization(TranslatableModel, Entity):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Name"), max_length=200),
        description = RichTextField(verbose_name=_("Description"), blank=True, null=True, config_name='default')
    )
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Status"), max_length=50),
```

organizations.json:

```
[
    {
        "model": "app.organization",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "status": "Active"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "app.organization",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "status": "Active",
        }
    }
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

as the translations are stored in an own model/table you will need to call

`python manage.py dumpdata app.OrganizationTranslation -o fixtures/organization_tranlsations.json`